# ZAP: Exploring APIs - how to set header parameters in UI?

Tags: zap

I'm evaluating ZAP and followed the guide:  https://zaproxy.blogspot.ru/2017/04/exploring-apis-with-zap.html

But cannot find a way how to set header parameters in the UI, for example api key.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Replacer addon: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/replacer/

Or a script. Here's a python scripting example:

```
headers = dict({"X-MIP-ACCESS-TOKEN": "XXXXXxXX-xxXX-XXXx-xxxX-XXxxXxXXxXxX",
                "X-MIP-CHANNEL": "ANDROID",
                "X-MIP-Device-Id": "1",
                "X-MIP-APP-VERSION": "1.0.1",
                "X-MIP-APP-VERSION-ID": "1"});

def sendingRequest(msg, initiator, helper): 
    for x in list(headers):
      msg.getRequestHeader().setHeader(x, headers[x]);


def responseReceived(msg, initiator, helper): 
    pass;
```

You can find other examples in the community-scripts repo: https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts

You can get the Replacer add-on or python scripting add-on via the ZAP Marketplace:
[image]

Comment: @alexander-kjäll thanks for the updated link :)